# Illustrator: Quick way of removing redundant anchor points after unifying shapes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, workflow

Except for manually removing redundant anchor points that gets added when unifying two or more objects, is there a quicker operation to wipe in-between anchor points?

[image]

---

**EDIT**: To complement Lollero's answer below, here's the setting to automatically remove redundant points from Pathfinder operations (as embarrasingly simple as it may seem, I never thought of this before):

[image]

Comment: I know this doesn't help you, but had to reminisce about how Freehand used to make this so easy to do. RIP Freehand. You are missed. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand does just that:

http://www.bittbox.com/illustrator/pathfinder-explained

Also:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6456.html

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. (I updated my question with a screenshot.)

Comment: "Expand" didn't remove any points for me, even when I tick "remove redundant points" in pathfinder's options, I get a lot of points I don't need and simplify adds useless points everywhere. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Both links are rotten

Answer (score 3):

You can go to *Object → Simplify*, and then choose how much line accuracy you want. If you want to keep the same shape, choose 100%. If you click on *preview* it will tell you how many points you will reduce.

Answer (score -1):

Select the path which has more anchor points than you desire.

Now select Warp tool in the tools panel (in the left side). With this tool active, just drag over the path which you want to have lesser anchor points than it is having currently. The more you'll drag over that path, the more effect this tool would have.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to show what you mean ...

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Bobby, I think you mean the smooth tool?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I'm not half an expert as others are here. Sorry for interrupting the flow.