# Is there a way to stop Adobe Illustrator from adding anchors when using the Pathfinder or Shape Builder?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pathfinder, anchor-point

When using the <kbd>Effects > Stylize > Round Corners...</kbd> Illustrator option on shapes I built using Pathinfder and Shape Builder, I'm having a distinct problem with doouble anchor points. Since the effect does not round corners if they consist of multiple anchors, this spoils the effect at multiple places.

Take this shape, for example. The shape is fully expanded and consists of only a single path.

[image]

I built this using Pathfinder and Shape Builder. Look what happens when I round this shape's corners:
[image]

At the weirdest places, the Builder or the Pathfinder have created shapes using multiple anchors for a single point.

Is this adding of points preventable? If not, is it possible to remove them with a function? <kbd>Object > Simplify</kbd> does not seem to work, as it keeps the additional points even when not 100% accurately reproducing the shape.

The methods mentioned in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/illustrator-quick-way-of-removing-redundant-anchor-points-after-unifying-shapes) don't seem to work for the Shape Builder.

I'm working on cs6.

Comment: it would be possible to script deletion of overlapping consequtive points.

Comment: here's a script that removes overlapped or near-overlapped anchors http://shspage.com/aijs/en/

Comment: Rounded corners work well in simple shapes. actually I do round corners before I use Pathfinder. however if I am forced to use rounded corners for some complex shape, I use astute graphics vectorscribe plugin to do the job and to simply the shape with minimal possible anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pathfinder palette's options, under <kbd>Pahthfinder Options</kbd>, there's a checkmark for an option 'Remove Redundant Points' that does exactly this:

[image]